# Node Express Update MySql sintax

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have the following code, node express, trying to update mysql data base. Is this query syntax ok for node express?

```
await db.pool.query(`UPDATE canchaalunes SET created = ? where id=1 `,[data.user] )
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: yes, but it doesnt update the db

Comment: The actual query syntax does noo change regardess of which mechanism you use to submit it to the server. Its the way you code the call that may change depending on programming language

Comment: yes, it is javascript, it doesnt seem to work using the query this way

Comment: it does work. there was sthg wrong in my db. thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an error? Are you sure a record with that ID exists? Have you tried this query independent of Node?